# Timeout Error when Reading Measurements from Impedance Analyzer Solartron 1260 via NI MAX using IEEE 488/GPIB

Tags: impedance, error

I'm working with a Solartron A1260 Impedance/Gain-Phase Analyzer and attempting to read measurements on the NI MAX interface connected through a PCI bus. The analyzer itself is functioning correctly and can receive "Write" commands, as you can see the measurements on blue screen, but when I try to "Read" these measurements using NI MAX, I encounter a timeout error, as illustrated in the attached screenshot. The only command I can read is `*IDN?` . but my goal is to "Read" that simple measurement data of impedance analyzer on NI MAX interface.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Device Model: Solartron 1260 Impedance/Gain-Phase Analyzer
- Connection: Interface through PCIB
- Software: NI MAX
- Issue: Timeout error EABO during GPIB read operation
- Troubleshooting Steps: Adjusted timeout settings, adjusted bytes, changed addresses, checked GPIB command syntax, changed GPIB and termination characters !

I have tried adjusting the timeout/Bytes settings and reviewing the connection, but the issue persists. It seems like the main challenge is that I'm not sure about the correct commands to read the measurement data.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on the proper GPIB commands for reading measurements from a Solartron 1260 or any troubleshooting steps that might resolve this timeout error.

[image: Simple Measurment using NIMax]

[[image: Visa Test Panel of NiMax][2]]

[image: Time Out Error]